# Karma Coverage not picking up everything using Webpack

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, aurelia, karma-coverage

So I am able to get my karma coverage to run.

```
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File              |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
 src/             |    91.49 |     62.5 |    93.33 |    97.56 |                |
  app.js          |    91.67 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                |
  child-router.js |    91.67 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                |
  users.js        |     91.3 |       75 |    85.71 |    95.24 |             24 |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files         |    91.49 |     62.5 |    93.33 |    97.56 |                |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

The problem is I have other files inside of the `src/` folder that it doesn't seem to be detecting. For example I have added a `src/test.js` that isn't being picked up by coverage. I am not sure why coverage is picking up only a portion of the files inside of `/src`.

Here is my Karma.Config:

```
/*eslint-disable no-var*/

var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
webpackConfig.entry = {};

// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Feb 26 2016 14:25:47 GMT+0100 (CET)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'build/bundle.js',
      'test/unit/**/*.spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      //'build/bundle.js': ['webpack'], // why is this here??
      'test/**/*.js': ['webpack'],
      'src/**/*.js': ['webpack']
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    coverageReporter: {
      dir: 'build/coverage',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
        { type: 'text'}
      ]
    },


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity,


    webpack: {
      module: {
        loaders: [{ test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/, query: { presets: ['es2015-loose', 'stage-1'], plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'] } }],
        postLoaders: [{
          test: /\.js$/, exclude: /(node_modules|test)/,
          loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter'
        }]
      }
    },

    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    }
  });
};
```